# WinInet store read file on a char/string c++

Tags: c++, wininet

```
#include <WinInet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet")

void download(std::string domain, std::string url)
{
    HINTERNET hIntSession = InternetOpenA("MyApp", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hHttpSession = InternetConnectA(hIntSession, domain.c_str(), 80, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);
    HINTERNET hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hHttpSession, "GET", url.c_str(), 0, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    TCHAR* szHeaders = "";
    CHAR szReq[1024] = "";
    if (!HttpSendRequest(hHttpRequest, szHeaders, wcslen(L""), szReq, strlen(szReq))){
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "No se puede conectar al Servidor de Actualizaciones.", "Error Kundun", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    TCHAR szBuffer[1025];
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    while (InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, szBuffer, 1024, &dwRead) && dwRead)
    {
        // What to do here?
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
    InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
}

download("www.something.com", "File.txt");
```

So I have this code to read something from a text file on my hosting. I managed to get that by googling and it seems to work just fine (if I put an incorrect domain it will show the messagebox with the error). The thing is.. I don't know how to put the info that I just read into a string or char[].

Comment: I'd suggest you first read all those "how to convert from TCHAR to ..." questions first before asking yet another one.

Comment: I already saw a lot of posts before posting, I just wanted some quick help >< But as I see for the downvotes, I think people don't like questions :/

Comment: I understand your statement that you "just wanted some quick help" as "I'm too lazy to do any research myself if it takes more than a negligible amount of time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `szBuffer` to `char[]` and then use [`std::string::append()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) inside your loop:

```
#include <WinInet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet")

void download(const std::string & domain, const std::string &url)
{
    HINTERNET hIntSession = InternetOpenA("MyApp", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hHttpSession = InternetConnectA(hIntSession, domain.c_str(), 80, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);
    HINTERNET hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hHttpSession, "GET", url.c_str(), 0, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
    if (!HttpSendRequestA(hHttpRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0))
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "No se puede conectar al Servidor de Actualizaciones.", "Error Kundun", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    char szBuffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    std::string data;
    while (InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, szBuffer, 1024, &dwRead) && dwRead)
    {
        data.append(szBuffer, dwRead);
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
    InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
    // use data as needed...
}
```